# Metal: No matching function for call to 'threadgroup_barrier' in the kernel or Use of undeclared identifier 'mem_threadgroup'

Tags: objective-c, c, opencl, gpgpu, metal

I am writing a compute function (a.k.a., kernel) using Apple's [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH1-SW1) for scientific computation.

In the kernel, I use the [threadgroup](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/std-lib/std-lib.html) memory space. (To my understanding, it is similar to *local* memory space in OpenCL - please correct me if I am wrong.)
To synchronize some memory read/write operations, I need to place threadgroup_barrier(mem_threadgroup). However, the barrier command keeps generateing errors:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'mem_threadgroup.'
```

Even when I remove the argument to the function call (threadgroup_barrier()), I get an error:

```
No matching function for call to 'threadgroup_barrier' in the kernel.
```

I included the header 'metal_stdlib' in the kernel. What am I missing here? Is there another header that I need to use to use the barrier?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Here is the code summary:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void myKernel(device float2 *args [[buffer(0)]],
                    uint2 bidx [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]],
                    uint2 tidx [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]])
{
    // memory space shared by thread groups
    threadgroup float2 tile[32][32+1];

    ...

    for (uint k = 0; k < params.depth; k++)
    {
       ... // operations with tile (threadgroup memory space)

       threadgroup_barrier(mem_threadgroup);

       ... // more operations with tile

       threadgroup_barrier(mem_threadgroup);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Thanks to my colleague who helped find the fix.]
Since mem_flags is an enum class, I need the scope resolution operator (mem_flags::). So, the correct usage of the barrier is

```
threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup)
```

This fix eliminated the errors.